# To traverse collections, aggregate operation is better option how?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have recently learned that to traverse collections aggregate operations is better option than for-each construct or Iterator but i didn't figure out how .
What's the benefits to obtain a stream and perform aggregate operations.
Is there any performance issue or just simplicity of syntex?

Comment: I added the Java-8 tag since you seem to be asking about streams.

Comment: try to do some multi-threaded aggregate operation using plain for-each and you will see how hard it is. You need to synchronize a lot of stuff etc because list is not thread safe.. You can achieve the same thing using streams by just using parallel stream, it's much easier and safe. Saves a lot of time. Also, streams let you focus on the question 'what' rather than how because they take the 'how' part away. The iteration is done internally for you out of the box.

Comment: The primary benefit is neither performance (thought it performs well) nor simplicity of syntax (though this may also be a benefit.)  The benefit is _expressing the operation at a higher level of abstraction_, as a property of the data set, rather than an imperative process that grovels over each individual element and computes some ad-hoc result.

Answer (score 1):

One of the main differences between Aggregate Operations and Iterators (or for-each loops) is that the first uses internal iteration. As Oracle docs says:

> "external iteration can only iterate over the elements of a collection
>   sequentially. Internal iteration does not have this limitation. It can
>   more easily take advantage of parallel computing". Ref: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/index.html#differences